# async keyword in module name is preventing import

Tags: python, python-3.7, pymodbus

I'm trying to use pymodbus under *Python 3.7.2* and Windows 10. There is a module named pymodbus.server.async that works without issue in *Python 2.7.14*. Under 3.7 is looks like async is now a keyword and that is preventing the module from being imported. I get this error:

```
from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a proper way around this? As a temporary stop gap, renamed the module to bsync but this is not a sustainable solution.

Comment: Use it instead: `pymodbus.client.asynchronous` or `pymodbus.client.aio` in Python3.7

Answer (score 1):

Solution found [pymodbus rc branch](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/320). Module was renamed to `asynchronous`.